# Not able to query attachment coming from email to case

Tags: apex, trigger, class, email2case

Why is the attachment blank even though i have attached one while creating case from email.

```
List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id,OwnerId,
                         (SELECT id,Name,ContentType FROM Attachments 
                         Where ParentId IN (SELECT id FROM EmailMessage)),
                         (SELECT id,TextBody,Subject,FromName,HtmlBody, ParentId 
                         FROM EmailMessages) 
                         FROM Case WHERE (DWL__c = null AND Id IN (SELECT ParentId 
                         FROM EmailMessage))];
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Lightning Experience, the attachments are being saved on a different object/table called `ContentDocument`.

The binary data itself is stored in a related object called `ContentVersion`, and a object called `ContentDocumentLink` serves as a junction object for other system objects (so the file is related to a Case or an Opportunity, for example).

Be warned though, there are restrictions when querying `ContentDocumentLink`, like this:

> Implementation restriction: ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator or multiple Id's using the IN operator.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm